# Не могу установить библиотеку psycopg2

Tags: python, windows, psycopg2

Работаю на windows 10, при попытках написать `pip install psycopg2` консоль выкидывает эту ошибку

```
...
...
...
...

       Создается библиотека build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\psycopg\_psycopg.cp38-win32.lib и объект build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\psycopg\_psycopg.cp3
8-win32.exp
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfreemem"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQencryptPasswordConn"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQencryptPassword"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQinitOpenSSL"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconninfoParse"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQerrorMessage"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQlibVersion"
    psycopgmodule.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconninfoFree"
    green.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQclear"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQbinaryTuples"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsetnonblocking"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetvalue"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQresultStatus"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQoidValue"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQcmdStatus"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsocket"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQftablecol"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQputCopyData"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQstatus"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQisBusy"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconsumeInput"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQresultErrorField"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfsize"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfname"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsendQuery"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetCopyData"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQftable"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQflush"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQftype"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQnfields"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQresultErrorMessage"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQexec"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfmod"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQcmdTuples"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQntuples"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQresStatus"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQputCopyEnd"
    pqpath.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetResult"
    utils.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQescapeString"
    utils.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQescapeStringConn"
    utils.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQescapeIdentifier"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconnectPoll"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQserverVersion"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQnotifies"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsetNoticeProcessor"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetCancel"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfinish"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQprotocolVersion"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQfreeCancel"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconnectdb"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconnectStart"
    connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQparameterStatus"
    connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQcancel"
    connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQtransactionStatus"
    connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQbackendPID"
    connection_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconninfo"
    cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetisnull"
    cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQgetlength"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsslInUse"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconnectionNeedsPassword"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQpass"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQdb"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsslAttribute"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQport"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQoptions"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQconnectionUsedPassword"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQsslAttributeNames"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQuser"
    conninfo_type.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQhost"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_truncate"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_write"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_export"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_import"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_creat"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_read"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_tell"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_create"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_lseek"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_unlink"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_open"
    lobject_int.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_lo_close"
    adapter_binary.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQescapeByteaConn"
    adapter_binary.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_PQescapeBytea"
    build\lib.win32-3.8\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp38-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 83
    error: command 'D:\\Visual Studio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "D:\ORM\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\sulyi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8lkdqc6m\\
psycopg2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
" install --record C:\Users\sulyi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8y26e54t\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install
-headers D:\ORM\venv\include\site\python3.8\psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sulyi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8lkdqc6m\psycopg2\
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае не хватает сишных библиотек, которые позволили бы скомпилировать модуль.
Но можно пойти совершенно другим путем и скачать сразу бинарники.
Для этих случаев я находил бинарь здесь

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

подходящий под разрядность системы и версию питона, а затем устанавливал через pip install.

```
> pip install psycopg2-2.8.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing d:\experiment\psycopg2-2.8.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.4
```

В моем случае 64-разрядная система и питон 3.6